# moving models to a new django application

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

In my django project, I have an application which handles two models (two mysql tables), I noticed that I'd better create a new application with one the previous models. So the question is: how can I do it with south? given that I know another way without south and which consists on creating a new application, syncdb, then moving data from the old table to the new one using shell/python script and at last removing the old table. But I'd like to be a gentleman&stylish :D

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you'd do what you describe with South migrations.

1. Create an initial migration to define the schema
   `schemamigration <new_app_name> --initial`
2. Create a [data migration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations) to copy the data from one application to another 
   `datamigration <new_app_name> <migration_name>`
   You'll need to modify the file that is created in the `.forward()` `.backward()` methods to define how you want to move data
3. Create a schema migration on the initial application to delete the table 
   `schemamigration <original_app_name> -auto`

As you need the data to exist in the original app, apply the new app first and then the original app when calling migrate.

Comment: Thanks, it looks the best way to solve it, but I had errors when schemamigration --auto new_app such as: `CommandError: One or more models did not validate: 
original_app.internaute: Accessor for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.internaute'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.`
`original_app: Reverse query name for 'user' clashes with related field 'User.internate'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.`
`new_app.internaute: Accessor for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.internaute'. Add a related_name argument to `

Comment: So I renamed the table on the mysql terminal :/, to avoid all this